# Can't add height:auto to the background

Tags: html, wordpress, css

please see [here](http://glamourina.pl/czerwona-krata/).

I'd like to give a solid color to the comments area. This background color should enlarge according to the comments area. If there are a lot of comments it should have a big height, few comments, little height.

I have added the `<section class="comment">` inside a new div called `<div id="commentsbackground">` and I gave the following css:

```
#commentsbackground {
width: 6000px;
margin-left: -1172px;
background-color: #A6A8AF;
    }

section.comment {
height: 500px;
margin-left: 1172px;}
```

With this I managed to add the large background that should work with all big monitor resolutions. Not sure if there was a simple way to do it.... but for sure it's not working as I'd like to.

I'd like to have `height: auto;`, but it doesn't work.

I hope you can help me to have the comments area with a different background color.
This should be the final result:

-post area -> white 
-comments area -> grey 
-footer -> black

Comment: `margin-left: -1172px;`? Consider learning CSS Positioning

Comment: Try using **`float`**, for all the objects inside `#commentsbackground`.

Comment: And why not overflow:auto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Well,** if you use **overflow auto**, all the gray background will fill all the screen :P

```
#commentsbackground {
width: 6000px;
margin-left: -1172px; /*Idk, why do you use that*/
background-color: #A6A8AF;
overflow:auto;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about overflow. It works. I am using `margin-left: -1172px;` because I tried in many ways to have the background color to exist the `<div id="layout">` but I couldn't find any solution. So I had to create the `<div id="commentsbackground">`, make it very large in width, but when I make it large, it moves the comments to the right, that's why I had to put a `margin-left` of such value.<br>
I have no idea about any other possible and more logic solution

Comment: Ok, do you want that I edit the question for you? Or, are you satisfied?

Comment: I understand there is a better way to achieve the same without using `margin-left: -1172px;`? If yes, I'd be glad to know how.

Answer (score 1):

Either change containers to float:left or add a clearing method: http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

Comment: Not sure why I was marked down? My answer is two correct ways to fix the problem.